# PHP Public function that calls multiple private functions

Tags: php

I am trying to separate my interface and implementation. So I have a bunch of functions that perform various tasks. I originally had them all as Public and then I would call them from other pages. I am trying to tighten this up by making all of the real workload functions private and then using 1 public function to call them.

Here's what I am trying:

```
class TestClass
{

    public function pub1()
    {

       $this->test1();
       $this->test2();
       $this->test3();

    }

    private function test1()
        {

         $t1 = '1'; 

         return $t1

         }

    private function test2()
        {

         $t2 = '2'; 

         return $t2

         }

    private function test3()
        {

         $t3 = '3'; 

         return $t3

         }
}
```

I think this works but I cannot figure out how to call the functions. I can call pub1() fine but I cannot seem to call the functions below test1(), test2(), test3().

I can make this work if I do a one for one of the public to private functions but I was hoping to not have to do that.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: The real problem in unclear from your question. Your `pub1` calls the private methods that return strings. So?

Comment: of course you can't call `test1()`, `test2()`, and `test3()`... they're private

Comment: Put `echo` before each function call. `echo $this->test1(); echo $this->test2(); echo $this->test3();`. You'll see it's working.

Comment: Private functions can only be called within the class itself. If you want to call a function from outside the scope of the class, it will have to be public.

Comment: Such an abstract example. There's no way to tell if you should make Test1 public or not, nor whether it is a good idea to call them from Pub. Please provide a real life example and we *may* be able to advise you. In its current form, this question is pointless.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish.?

Answer (score 3):

Your call to pub1() should be correctly calling test1(), test2(), and test3() as you have written it. However, your test functions are returning a value, which your pub1() function then throws away. If you don't need to actually return anything from those test functions to the caller, then you should be ok as is.

Comment: +1 for the help. I need to rework this configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your design.

Objects have a strong relation with the real world. See the object as a black box, and look what properties and methods you need on the outside.

So:

- if you want to call a function outside of a class use a public.
- If you want to call a function inside a class or in a derived class, use protected.
- If you want to call a function only inside a class, use private.

If you have a interface, define it! And let a class implement it.

Comment: +1 for the help. This is helpful. I need to rework this configuration though. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Maybe something like this?

```
public function pub1 ($name) {
    return $this->$name();
}
```